# bluetooth android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Приложение вылетает если блюзуз на устройстве не включен

```
D/bluetooth:  onResume - попытка соединения
E/BluetoothDevice: Bluetooth is not enabled
D/bluetooth:  ....соединяемся...
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.jeka.toolcarcontrol, PID: 21370
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.jeka.toolcarcontrol/com.example.jeka.toolcarcontrol.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect()' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4221)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4323)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3426)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect()' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.jeka.toolcarcontrol.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:110)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1287)
                      at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7015)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4210)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4323) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3426) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21370 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Вот код приложения

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String Tag = "bluetooth";
    ImageButton img_button_up, img_button_down;
    TextView parameter1;
    Handler handler;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
    OutputStream outputStream;
    private StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    private ConectionTread conectionTread;

    private static final UUID my_uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
    private static final String module_adress = "20:13:01:29:12:61";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_xml_land);

        img_button_up = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img_but_up);
        img_button_down = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img_but_down);
        parameter1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.parm1);

        handler = new Handler(){
            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what){
                case 1:
                    byte[] readBuffer = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    String strIncom = new String(readBuffer, 0, msg.arg1);
                    int end_of__line_indx = stringBuilder.indexOf(";"); //not working, return -1
                    Log.d(Tag, strIncom);
                    Log.d(Tag, String.valueOf(end_of__line_indx));
                    if (end_of__line_indx > 0){
                        String strBuild_print = stringBuilder.substring(0, end_of__line_indx); //get text, from 0 index to last index
                        stringBuilder.delete(0, stringBuilder.length());
                        parameter1.setText("param 1: " + strBuild_print);
                        Log.d(Tag, strIncom);
                    }
                }
             }
        };

        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        chackBluetoothState();

        img_button_up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                conectionTread.write("1");  // Send 1 to module
            }
        });
        img_button_down.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                conectionTread.write("0");
            }
        });

    }

        @Override
        public void onStart(){
            super.onStart();
            if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume(){
            super.onResume();
                Log.d(Tag, " onResume - попытка соединения");

                BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(module_adress);

                try {
                    bluetoothSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(my_uuid);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    errorExit("Fatal Error", "Ошибка в onResume, проблема создания сокета " + e.getMessage());
                }

                Log.d(Tag, " ....соединяемся...");

                try {
                    bluetoothSocket.connect();
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Соединение установлено", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d(Tag, "...Соединение установлено и готово к передаче данных...");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    try {
                        bluetoothSocket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        Log.d(Tag, "..Ошибка закрытия порта...");
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Соединение не установлено", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d(Tag, "...Соединение не установлено...");
                }
                Log.d(Tag, "..Создание Сокета..");

                try {
                    outputStream = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    errorExit("Fatal Error", " Ошибка в onResume, не удалось создать выходной поток " + e.getMessage());
                }
                conectionTread = new ConectionTread(bluetoothSocket);
                conectionTread.start();
        }
    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();

        Log.d(Tag, "...InPause..");
        if (outputStream != null) {
            try {
                outputStream.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                errorExit("Fatal Error", "ошибка в onPause(), не удалось очистить выходной поток " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        try {
            bluetoothSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            errorExit("Fatal Error", " ошибка в onPause, не удалось закрыть сокет" + e1.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void chackBluetoothState() {
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null){
            errorExit("Fatal Error", "Bluetooth не поддерживается");
            finish();
            }
        }

    private void errorExit(String title, String massage) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), title + " - " + massage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }

    class ConectionTread extends Thread{
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInputStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConectionTread(BluetoothSocket socket){
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream streamIn = null;
            OutputStream streamOut = null;

            try {
                streamIn = socket.getInputStream();
                streamOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mmInputStream = streamIn;
            mmOutStream = streamOut;
        }
        public void run(){
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            int bytes;

            while (true){
                try {
                    //Read InputStream
                    if (mmInputStream != null) {
                        bytes = mmInputStream.read(buffer); // get byteArray in "buffer"
                        handler.obtainMessage(1, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget(); // send message to Handler
                    }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        public void write(String message){
            Log.d(Tag, "...Данные для отправки: " + message );
            byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();
            try {
                if(mmOutStream != null)
                mmOutStream.write(msgBuffer);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(Tag, "...Ошибка отправки данных: " + e.getMessage() + "...");
            }
        }
        public void cancel(){
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А в чем проблема-то? Вы не понимаете, почему программа вылетает?

Так в стек-трейсе же ясно написано:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect()' on a null object reference
```

То есть у Вас `bluetoothSocket == null`.

**UPD.** Вы можете проверить, включен ли `bluetooth` [таким образом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7672404/7129209):

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
    // Device does not support Bluetooth
} else {
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        // Bluetooth is not enable :)
    }
}
```

Далее, если `bluetooth` выключен, то Вы можете попросить пользователя включить его, если же устройство не поддерживает `bluetooth`, то показать соответствующее уведомление.

**UPD 2**. В методе `onStart()` Вы просите пользователя включить `bluetooth` запуская `startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);`, но дело в том, что метод `onResume()` (в котором вы пытаетесь коннектиться) срабатывает раньше того, как пользователь включит `bluetooth` (если вообще включит). Вам необходимо в методе `onActivityResult(...)` получать результат, и, если пользователь включил `bluetooth`, то производить коннект.

Comment: я это понимаю)мне нужно что бы сначала юзеру предлагалось включить блютуз а потом уже продолжить работу, а так то и выходит что сокет == null, извините не описал должным образом проблему

Comment: @UjinUkr, Смотрите **UPD**.

Comment: если вы посмотрите в мой код, а точнее в методы chackBluetoothState() и onStart() то поймете что я делаю практически тоже самое что вы описали

Comment: @UjinUkr, Значит у Вас выполняется коннект до того, как Вы включаете `bluetooth`.

Comment: И вообще, я не очень понимаю, зачем Вы выполняете коннект в `onResume()`. Вот Вы стартуете `startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);` и уже в зависимости от того, что оно Вам вернет, Вы должны либо выполнять коннект, либо нет.

Comment: Почему вас смутило что connect происходит в onResume()?посоветуйте бы вы сделали

Comment: @UjinUkr, Смотрите **UPD 2** в ответе.